# Toilet Water supply shut off valve

Tags: toilet

How many inches of copper pipe does there need to be for a Sharkbite angle shut off valve to be installed for a toilet water supply?

Comment: Don't forget to allow for the depth of the trim plate.

Comment: Don't forget about depth required to use the removal tool when you eventually need to replace the angle shutoff.

Answer (score 6):

That would depend on the pipe/valve size which you did not disclose. Here is the table.

[image]

[Source](https://manuals.plus/sharkbite/sharkbite-installation-manual#installation_guide)

I use marker pen to mark the insertion depth so not doubts here

Comment: Good answer.... not a lot of wordiness. :-)

Comment: @JACK almost like you, straight to the point

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Per request, Link included